# ImageView in ViewPager doesnt get correct Height

Tags: android, imageview

I have a list with userEntries. Each of these entries contains one block where I have some dynamic content, in this case a viewpager containing 1-3 images. My problem comes when I want to these images to have the correct Height. If I set my ViewPager height to for example 100dp the image is shown and the ViewPager works as expected. However if I rotate the phone or use a screen that is abit larger the image stays the same width as the 100dp is limiting it from getting the correct width. As this happends I want to use wrap_content so it resizes its height in order to fill the image to its full width, but when I do that the layout is minimized. See screens and code below.

> **CustomViewHolder.java** <- This holds the userentry

```
public void populateContentArea(int mListType, Context context){
    switch (mListType){
        case Constants.ListType.DATE_LIST:
            DatingEntryModel dateUser = (DatingEntryModel)mUser;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View datingContent = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dating_picture_container, llUserEntryContent, true);
            ViewPager datingPager = (ViewPager) datingContent.findViewById(R.id.datingPager);
            datingPager.setAdapter(new DatingPictureAdapter(context, dateUser.activities));
            TabLayout datingIndicator = (TabLayout) datingContent.findViewById(R.id.datingTabDots);
            datingIndicator.setupWithViewPager(datingPager);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

> **dating_picture_container.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/datingPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/datingTabDots"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="10dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_dot_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> **DatingPictureAdapter.java**

```
public class DatingPictureAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        List<DatingActivity> mActivities;

        public DatingPictureAdapter(Context context, List<DatingActivity> activities) {
            mContext = context;
            mActivities = activities;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
            DatingActivity activity = mActivities.get(position);
            final ImageView datingBanner = new ImageView(mContext);
            datingBanner.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            datingBanner.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            UrlManager.loadDatingBannerGlide(mContext, activity.id).into(datingBanner);
            collection.addView(datingBanner, 0);
            return datingBanner;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mActivities.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }
    }
```

[image: ImageView and ViewPager working but width wont resize as height is hardcoded]

[image: ImageView gone with wrap_content]

> At the end of the day, setting the height static to 10dp and then resize depending on the image width was the best solution for me. Thanks for all responses :)

Comment: where is your view pager items   xml file?

Comment: I have tried using a XML file and inflate the ImageView in but it yielded the same results as just creating an imageview and add to the viewpager so I just thought it was alot of code where it just "works" by adding the ImageView to the ViewPager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of you set your `ViewPager's` height "`wrap_content`" `wrap_content` does not work for `ViewPager`. If you change it to `match_parent` or to a static dp your issue'll be fixed.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/datingPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="144dp"/>
```

Comment: Alright, I had no idea wrap_content didnt work on ViewPager. Thanks. But I knew it worked by setting a hardcoded height, but that makes it look super bad on diffrent screen sizes. So somehow I need to set the height dynamically by getting the height the image should have. I have to try some diffrent methods and Ill see if I can get it to work :).

Comment: you can use different xml dimensions for different screen sizes. I suggest you to use static height with different dimensions and scaleType center.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 ways to do that:
1- if you want to use differents layouts with different orientation you must create one layout for each orientation
2- you can get progammatically get the height of display and put inside layout dinamically proportional height

i hope this help you

Comment: When I try to change the height programmatically nothing changes, and I have set the orientation correct I think in the xml's.. Saw I had vertical orientation on the RelativeLayout that shouldnt be need I think ;). Thanks for throwing some thoughts into this :)

Comment: something else that you can try programmatically is set also weight property, that is the proportional property of widgets

Comment: Ah, havent tried that. Ill see what it does. Edit: Didnt do anything :(

Comment: if answers help you, please quote to help other people to resolve same problem